# How to get data from server repeatedly in React + Redux application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am developing React + Redux single page application. I have a table with documents in page and I need to **refresh data** every 20 seconds. There are two functions in javascript: **setTimeout** and **setInterval**. I guess I can't use **setInterval**, because it just call function after some period of time. In my case I need to call function and wait for response (request processing in backend takes some time). So I used **setTimeout** and wrote this component (now it's simplified):

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const { DATA_REFRESH_TIMEOUT, RETRY_REFRESH_TIMEOUT } = __ENVIRONMENT_CONFIG__;

@connect(
    (state) => ({
        documents: state.documents.documents,
        loadingDocuments: state.documents.loading
    }),
    (dispatch) => bindActionCreators(
        {
            dispatchLoadDocuments: loadDocuments
        },
        dispatch
    )
)

export default class Dashboard extends Component {

    documentasTimeoutId;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            documentType: null
        };
    }
    ....

    handleDocumentTypeChange = (event, documentType) => {
        //If document type was changed I must to abort current timer
        //and get documents with particular type immediately
        this.setState({documentType: documentType});
        this.clearTimeoutAndGetDocuments(documentType);
    };

    getDocuments = (documentType) => {
        //Here I am checking for document loading phase
        //If it is loading, we will wait and repeat loading after short time 
        const{ loadingDocuments } = this.props;
        if(!loadingDocuments) {
            this.props.dispatchLoadDocuments(documentType);
        } else {
            this.documentasTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => { this.getDocuments(documentType); }, RETRY_REFRESH_TIMEOUT);
        }
    };

    clearTimeoutAndGetDocuments = (documentType) => {
        //Abort delayed data getting and get data immediately
        clearTimeout(this.documentasTimeoutId);
        this.getDocuments(documentType);
    };

    componentDidMount(){
        //Load documents on start up
        this.props.dispatchLoadDocuments();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        //Here I trying to get event when documents loaded
        let areDocumentsJustLoaded = this.props.loadingDocuments &&  !newProps.loadingDocuments;
        if(areDocumentsJustLoaded) {
            //If they loaded, I am setting timeout to refresh documents after some time
            this.documentasTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => { this.getOutstandingFailures(this.state.search); }, DATA_REFRESH_TIMEOUT);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {columns, documents} = this.props;

        return (
            //.....
            <DataTable
                columns={columns}
                source={documents}
                title="Documents"
                name="documents"
                emptyMessage="No data"/>
            //....
        );
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm getting **documents** and **loadingDocuments** from reducer. I put **documents** to my DataTable, and by **loadingDocuments** changes I can define when data loading completed.

It's working, but I'am not sure for correct react and redux using (I am a newbie in React/Redux). Maybe there a better approach to do same actions? Maybe we can somehow create a separate component for this purpose and reuse it in other pages?

Comment: It seems to me you should not attempt to control the document loading in the component. It forces you to introduce state, which defeats the purpose of redux. Maybe you could implement a redux middleware instead.

Comment: Could you provide an example?